# Stop Zurb Foundation Top bar scrolling page when clicking menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a fixed top-bar menu with zurb, contained to grid. Above the Menu (before scroll) is an additional menu which is scrolled off screen and then the zurb top-bar is fixed. This is correct.

However, when you then click the menu icon the page scroll then goes to the top of the page meaning the first menu comes back into view. This isn't so much of a problem until you collapse the menu again which reveals the layout to be screwed up.

I've tried disabling scroll through scolltop : false in the JS file, and inline in the html with data-options but it doesn't seem to do anything!

Any guidance would be appreciated!

Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="contain-to-grid sticky">

<nav class="top-bar">
  <ul class="title-area">

<!-- Title Area -->

   <li class="name">
    <h1><a href="#"><img src="img/parts/clouds.png" alt="Scan and Share Photo Scanning"></a>    </h1>

    <div id="secondary-logo"><img src="img/parts/scan-share.png" width="267" height="79" alt="Scan old Photos"> </div>
  </li>

<!-- Remove the class "menu-icon" to get rid of menu icon. Take out "Menu" to just have icon alone -->

  <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>

</ul>

<section class="top-bar-section">

<!-- Left Nav Section -->

<ul class="left"> <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">WHY USE US</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">BLOG</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Right Nav Section -->

</section>
</nav>
</div>
</div>
```

The link to the dev site is http://scanshare.webdevspace.co.uk

The documentation is here: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/top-bar.html